# Update GUI from worker thread works (WinForms), why?

Tags: multithreading, winforms, controls

**WinForms** (VS2015 / .NET 4.6)

In my background thread

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
 {
    ...
    _callback?.Progress("abcd");
    ...
 });
```

I call the GUI (_callback), which implements an interface in the Form class.
Here, I modify textbox, progressbar, etc values.

```
void IWorkerCallback.Log(string message)
{
    _textBoxLog.AppendText($"{message}{Environment.NewLine}");
    ++_progressBar.Value;
    .... etc...
}
```

And all works fine!
If I break in with debugger, I could see that the `Form.IWorkerCallback.Log()` function is executed in the worker thread context (in Threads debug window).

It's said everywhere that you MUST change GUI items only on the GUI thread (where they are created), otherwise you get `System.InvalidOperationException` exception with `cross-thread operation not valid.....`

But it works fine for me.

Could you explain, why?

Thanks

Comment: This is undefined behavior. It may work or not. To get consistent failure on cross-thread calls set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true` in the beginning of the program.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls?view=netframework-4.8  On lower Windows API level, cross-thread UI calls that don't use thread local storage or any other thread-specific resources, may be executed successfully.

Comment: @AlexF - yes, that's it, `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is the trick! If you write it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: That's what [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) is for. It can be called from either a different thread or the main thread. You don't need to check `InvokeRequired`. No need to consider whether you have a debugger attached or not.

Comment: Yes I know that, but was surprised it works w/o begininvoke()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running UI calls from another thread is undefined behavior. It may work or not. To get consistent failure on cross-thread calls set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` in the beginning of the program:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls?view=netframework-4.8

From MSDN documentation:

> When a thread other than the creating thread of a control tries to access one of that control's methods or properties, it often leads to unpredictable results. A common invalid thread activity is a call on the wrong thread that accesses the control's Handle property. Set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to true to find and diagnose this thread activity more easily.

On low Windows API level, cross-thread UI calls that don't use thread local storage or any other thread-specific resources, may be executed successfully. However, we still have thread synchronization problem, so result is also undefined.